# How to check if code execution comes from tests in Play2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I don't want to execute some code when it comes from test (Specs2)
For eg. emailers.

How can i check that my code is executing from tests?
I use fakeApplication and TestServer in my specs.

Alternative i could check my database driver (h2 for tests and postgres for production) this way.

```
import play.api.Play.current

  def isFromTests:Boolean={
    Play.application.configuration.getString("db.default.driver") match {
      case Some("org.h2.Driver") => true
      case _ =>false
    }
  }
```

But is there a better one? Sometimes i run my app with h2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `play.Play.isTest()` method to check if you are running in test mode.